# how to delete terms in plugin? woocommerce

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce

i am creating a plugin with plugin hooks when plugin activate it creating product attributes it working fine also i adding attributes terms it also working fine and on plugin deactivate i am deleting it but i see only attributes deleting but terms not delete.

i using this code for deleting attributes it working fine

```
enter code here
// attributes parameters
$wpm_attributes = array(
    array(
        'label' => 'Size',
        'name' => 'size',
        'type' => 'select',
    ),
    array(
        'label' => 'Color',
        'name' => 'color',
        'type' => 'select',
    )
);

foreach ( $wpm_attributes as $attr ) {
    $attribute = array(
        'attribute_label'   => $attr['label'],
        'attribute_name'    => $attr['name'],
        'attribute_type'    => $attr['type'],
        'attribute_orderby' => 'menu_order'
    );
    $wpdb->delete( $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies', $attribute );
    delete_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies' );
}
```

Comment: i want also delete the attributes terms when plugin deactivate

Comment: please help me some one how to delete attributes terms?

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to delete terms on deactivate. If someone accidentally deactivates, why should they lose all their data?

Comment: i use this for woocommerce attributes color, size etc.. there is not any data

Comment: But what happens if people have products with color, size, etc attributes assigned?

Answer (score 0):

```
I recommend not deleting the terms at the point of deactivation.

Instead why don't you delete the terms at the point of uninstallation?

You can use the uninstall hook:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook

Or bypass that.

The plugin should create a file named 'uninstall.php' in the base plugin folder. This file will be called, if it exists, during the uninstall process bypassing the uninstall hook.

This may be easier to manage code wise and sometimes people would like to deactivate a plugin and not lose all their data.
```